# JSON parsing problem in BlackBerry

Tags: json, parsing, blackberry

I'm working on how to parse Twitter's JSON response using JSON-ME.

For example:

```
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search
foo({"results":[{"profile_image_url":"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/762620209/drama_queen-6989_normal.gif","created_at":"Thu, 01 Apr 2010 02:35:10 +0000","from_user":"TWEETSDRAMA","to_user_id":null,"text":"NEW Twitter Lists Widget - How to put it on your blog or site http://bit.ly/47NCi6","id":11401539152,"from_user_id":95081097,"geo":null,"iso_language_code":"en","source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http://ping.fm/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Ping.fm&lt;/a&gt;"}... (content truncated)
```

Here's my method:

```
public void parseDataFromJSON(String strjson) throws JSONException {
JSONTokener jtoken = new JSONTokener(strjson);
JSONArray jsoarray = new JSONArray(jtoken);
JSONObject jsobj = jsoarray.getJSONObject(0);

tweeter_profile_image_url = jsobj.optString("profile_image_url");
tweeter_created_at = jsobj.optString("created_at");
tweeter_from_user = jsobj.optString("from_user");
tweeter_to_user_id = jsobj.optString("to_user_id");
tweeter_text = jsobj.optString("text");
tweeter_id = jsobj.optInt("id"); 
tweeter_from_user_id = jsobj.optInt("from_user_id");
tweeter_geo = jsobj.optString("geo");
tweeter_iso_language_code = jsobj.optString("iso_language_code");
tweeter_source = jsobj.optString("source")
}
```

When I ran it on the emulator, nothing was shown, so I inspected the debugger, and the output was:
status: 200
content: {"results":[{"profile_image_url":"http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/746683548/Photo_on_2010-..... ---> OK, I got the JSON content

org.json.me.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"results":[{"profile_image_url.... ---> but somehow unable to processed it properly.

So how to parse this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The response itself is an object, so you only need this to parse it:

```
JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject(strjson);
```

It's an object with a single key, "result", which is itself an array.  So you'd do something like this:

```
JSONArray jsoarray = jsobj.getJSONArray("results");
```

Then each element in the "jsoarray" array will be a JSONObject, etc. etc.  You can see how the different JSON objects are nested within each other...

Comment: OK. I'm still confused.

There are lots of elements (JSONObjects) in jsoarray.

Let's say I want to access the first element:
    JSONObject foo = jsoarray.getJSONObject(0);

foo has lots of keys: profile_image_url, created_at, tweeter_id, etc. I'd like to know what value the "profile_image_url" has, so I do this:
    tweeter_profile_image_url = foo.getString("profile_image_url")
And it still crashes. Hmm...

Comment: If there's a chance that a key in the JSONObject may not exist, use optString instead of getString otherwise it will throw a JSONException.

Comment: Just tried this:
tweeter_profile_image_url = foo.optString("profile_image_url");

And it still crashes.

But when I try this:
Dialog.inform("foo.length(): " + foo.length());

The message box will says 11, which is correct.

Comment: Finally, I found the culprit. It's not the parsing itself (the parsing went find), but due to "synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock())".
I forgot to put that thing in my code.

Now the problem is solved. Many thanks, anyway.